# .svn/lock file access denied

Tags: windows, svn

I have got a SVN Server. Which worker perfect untill this morning (Last commit 10:35:39). There was a file created at the hidden .svn folder which is named "lock" at that commit time.

After the file was created I cannot COMMIT, UPDATE, CLEAN-UP and tried to login as Server admin. When I right click the file and select properties, the Security tab shows I do not have access to see the information. It is not possible to set myself as file admin. I can not delete the file.

Other checkout directories which also use the same SVN server still work.

Anyone knows how to delete this file or fix this issue?

Comment: tortoise svn or command line ?

Comment: Tortoise SVN for Windows.

Comment: You have the general "have you tried turning it off and on again" solution by doing a complete new checkout of the repository. But more specifically, you can usually fix this by doing right click => tortoise svn => cleanup. Release lock might do the trick too!

Comment: As my post says, I have tried to use the cleanup command. But it will say "Access denied". I have tried to create a new checkout. It will work. But I can't delete this file. Which means I have an empty directory on my server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, can you show us a print screen of the file? I'm kind of confused how you randomly created a file with elevated permissions.

Comment: Did you install the command line tools for SVN with Tortoise SVN ?

Comment: The screenshot is on top, the bottom screenshot is from the cleanup command http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/4239/naamlooshbw.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22594/discussion-between-niels-and-khez)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar access denied issue when trying to move a repo from another server. I was able to load the repo by **making sure I was the Owner of the target files**